# Visual studio 2010- Application as a service in release mode

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2010, service

I have an desktop console application created in visual studio 2010.How do i convert it to windows service?.  basically in debug mode i want it as normal app , but in release mode i want a service build  output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
namespace Program
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static bool Stopped = false;
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Interactive.Initialize();
            Interactive.OnStopped += new Interactive.StopedDelegate(OnStopped);
            Interactive.Title = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(
                Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

            if (args.Length == 0) Interactive.Run(RunProc);
            else if (args[0] == "-svc") ServiceBase.Run(new Service());
        }
        public static void RunProc() { yourConsoleMain(); }
        public static void OnStopped() { Stopped = true; exitFromMain(); }
    }

    public class Service : ServiceBase
    {
        public static string Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        public static string CmdLineSwitch = "-svc";
        public static ServiceStartMode StartMode = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
        public static bool DesktopInteract = true;
        public bool Stopped = false;
        public Service() { ServiceName = Name; }
        public void Start() { OnStart(null); }
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(
                ServiceName, ServiceName + " service started.");
            Thread thread = new Thread(MainThread);
            thread.Start();
        }
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(
                ServiceName, ServiceName + " service stopped.");
            Stopped = true;
            Application.Exit();
        }
        private void MainThread()
        {
            Interactive.Run(Program.RunProc);
            if (!Stopped) Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Let me explain this... Basically, in `Main` you define that your program starts as a service if it is started with argument `'-svc'`.

Put in `RunProc()` what you normally do in `main()`, and in `OnStopped()` event handler some code that will cause `main()` to exit.

Then, override `ServiceBase` and perform some basic start/stop service.

In Windows 7 and later you must explicitly define that your service can interact with desktop if you want to see some output. But there is another problem, console window cannot be shown. So I created this console simulator which can write and also read input.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ProgramIO.Control
{
    public delegate void WriteDelegate(string value, int x, int y);
    public delegate void ReadDelegate(out string value, bool readLine);
    public delegate void EnableInputDelegate(bool enable);

    public partial class InteractiveForm : Form
    {
        private delegate void ClearInputBufferDelegate();

        public enum EIOOperation { None = 0, Write, Read }

        private EventWaitHandle eventInvoke =
            new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
        private EventWaitHandle eventInput =
            new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
        private bool readLine = false;
        private string inputBuffer = "";
        private int inputPosition = 0;
        private int inputBufferPosition = 0;
        private EIOOperation IOOperation;
        private int bufferSize = 0x10000;
        private bool CaretShown = false;

        private delegate object DoInvokeDelegate(Delegate method, params object[] args);
        private delegate void SetTitleDelegate(string value);
        private delegate void SetForegroundcolorDelegate(Color value);

        public string Title {
            get { return Text; }
            set {
                if (InvokeRequired) InvokeEx(
                    (SetTitleDelegate)delegate(string title) { Text = title; },
                    1000, new object[] { value });
                else Text = value; }}
        public Color ForegroundColor {
            get { return ForeColor; }
            set {
                if (InvokeRequired) InvokeEx(
                    (SetForegroundcolorDelegate)delegate(Color color) { ForeColor = color; },
                    1000, new object[] { value });
                else ForeColor = value; }}

        public InteractiveForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DoubleBuffered = true;
        }

        #region Asynchronous Methods
        private bool InvokeEx(Delegate method, int timeout, params object[] args)
        {
            BeginInvoke((DoInvokeDelegate)DoInvoke, new object[] { method, args });
            if (eventInvoke.WaitOne(timeout)) return true;
            else return false;
        }
        private void EnableInput(bool enable)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
                InvokeEx((EnableInputDelegate)DoEnableInput, 1000, new object[] { enable });
            else DoEnableInput(enable);
        }
        private void ClearInputBuffer()
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
                InvokeEx((ClearInputBufferDelegate)DoClearInputBuffer, 1000, new object[0]);
            else DoClearInputBuffer();
        }
        public void Write(string value, int x = -1, int y = -1)
        {
            lock (this) {
                IOOperation = EIOOperation.Write;
                if (InvokeRequired)
                    InvokeEx((WriteDelegate)DoWrite, 1000, new object[] { value, x, y });
                else DoWrite(value, x, y);
                IOOperation = EIOOperation.None; }
        }
        public string Read(bool readLine)
        {
            lock (this) {
                EnableInput(true);
                IOOperation = EIOOperation.Read; this.readLine = readLine; string value = "";
                ClearInputBuffer(); eventInput.WaitOne();
                object[] args = new object[] { value, readLine };
                if (InvokeRequired) {
                    InvokeEx((ReadDelegate)DoRead, 1000, args); value = (string) args[0]; }
                else DoRead(out value, readLine);
                //inputPosition = textBox.Text.Length; inputBuffer = "";
                ClearInputBuffer();
                IOOperation = EIOOperation.None;
                EnableInput(false);
                return value;
            }
        }
        #endregion //Asynchronous Methods

        #region Synchronous Methods
        protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e) { base.OnShown(e); textBox.Focus(); }
        public object DoInvoke(Delegate method, params object[] args)
        {
            object obj = method.DynamicInvoke(args);
            eventInvoke.Set();
            return obj;
        }
        private void CorrectSelection()
        {
            if (textBox.SelectionStart < inputPosition) {
                if (textBox.SelectionLength > (inputPosition - textBox.SelectionStart))
                    textBox.SelectionLength -= inputPosition - textBox.SelectionStart;
                else textBox.SelectionLength = 0;
                textBox.SelectionStart = inputPosition; }
        }
        protected void DoClearInputBuffer()
        {
            inputPosition = textBox.Text.Length; inputBuffer = "";
        }
        protected void DoEnableInput(bool enable)
        {
            if (enable) { textBox.ReadOnly = false; textBox.SetCaret(true); }
            else { textBox.ReadOnly = true; textBox.SetCaret(false); }
        }
        protected void DoWrite(string value, int x, int y)
        {
            string[] lines = textBox.Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            string[] addLines = new string[0];

            if (y == -1) y = lines.Length - 1;
            if (lines.Length - 1 < y) addLines = new string[y - lines.Length - 1];

            if (y < lines.Length) {
                if (x == -1) x = lines[y].Length;
                if (lines[y].Length < x)
                    lines[y] += new String(' ', x - lines[y].Length) + value;
                else
                    lines[y] = lines[y].Substring(0, x) + value +
                        ((x + value.Length) < lines[y].Length ?
                            lines[y].Substring(x + value.Length) : ""); }
            else {
                y -= lines.Length;
                if (x == -1) x = addLines[y].Length;
                addLines[y] += new String(' ', x - addLines[y].Length) + value; }

            textBox.Text = (string.Join("\r\n", lines) +
                (addLines.Length > 0 ? "\r\n" : "") + string.Join("\r\n", addLines));
            textBox.Select(textBox.Text.Length, 0); textBox.ScrollToCaret();
            inputBuffer = "";
        }
        protected void DoRead(out string value, bool readLine)
        {
            value = "";
            if (readLine) {
                int count = inputBuffer.IndexOf("\r\n");
                if (count > 0) { value = inputBuffer.Substring(0, count); }}
            else if (inputBuffer.Length > 0) {
                value = inputBuffer.Substring(0, 1); }
            inputBuffer = "";
        }
        private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IOOperation == EIOOperation.Read) {
                inputBuffer = textBox.Text.Substring(inputPosition);
                if (!readLine || inputBuffer.Contains("\r\n")) eventInput.Set(); }

            if (textBox.Text.Length > bufferSize) { textBox.Text =
                textBox.Text.Substring(textBox.Text.Length - bufferSize, bufferSize);
                textBox.Select(textBox.Text.Length, 0); textBox.ScrollToCaret(); }
        }
        private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (IOOperation != EIOOperation.Read || 
                (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back && inputBuffer.Length == 0))
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
        private void textBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            CorrectSelection();
        }
        private void textBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(IOOperation == EIOOperation.Read) ||
                ((e.KeyCode == Keys.Left || e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) &&
                textBox.SelectionStart < inputPosition))
                CorrectSelection();
        }
        private void InteractiveForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            eventInput.Set();
            lock (this) { }
        }
        #endregion //Synchronous Methods
    }

    public class InteractiveWindow : TextBox
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool HideCaret(IntPtr hWnd);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ShowCaret(IntPtr hWnd);

        private delegate void SetCaretDelegate(bool visible);

        private const int WM_SETFOCUS = 0x0007;
        private bool CaretVisible = true;

        public void SetCaret(bool visible)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired) Invoke((SetCaretDelegate)DoSetCaret, new object[] { visible });
            else DoSetCaret(visible);
        }
        private void DoSetCaret(bool visible)
        {
            if (CaretVisible != visible)
            {
                CaretVisible = visible;
                if (CaretVisible) ShowCaret(Handle);
                else HideCaret(Handle);
            }
        }
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            if (m.Msg == WM_SETFOCUS)
            {
                if (CaretVisible) { ShowCaret(Handle); }
                else HideCaret(Handle);
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace ProgramIO
{
    using ProgramIO.Control;
    public static class Interactive
    {
        public delegate void StopedDelegate();
        public delegate void RunDelegate();

        public static bool Initialized = false;
        private static InteractiveForm frmIO = null;
        private static Thread IOThread = null;
        private static EventWaitHandle EventStarted =
            new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);

        public static string Title {
            get { return frmIO.Title; }
            set { frmIO.Title = value; } }
        public static Color ForegroundColor {
            get {return frmIO.ForeColor; }
            set { frmIO.ForeColor = value; } }
        public static event StopedDelegate OnStopped = null;

        private static void form_Show(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmIO = sender as InteractiveForm;
            EventStarted.Set();
        }
        private static void form_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            lock (frmIO) {
                frmIO = null;
                Application.Exit(); }
        }
        public static void Initialize()
        {
            IOThread = new Thread(IOThreadProc);
            IOThread.Name = "Interactive Thread"; IOThread.Start();
            EventStarted.WaitOne();
            Initialized = true;
        }
        public static void Run(RunDelegate runProc = null)
        {
            if (!Initialized) Initialize();
            if (runProc != null) runProc();
            Application.Run();
            if (OnStopped != null) OnStopped();
        }
        public static void IOThreadProc()
        {
            InteractiveForm form = new InteractiveForm();
            form.Shown += new EventHandler(form_Show);
            form.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(form_FormClosed);
            Application.Run(form);
        }
        public static void Write(string value, int x = -1, int y = -1)
        {
            if (frmIO != null) lock (frmIO) { frmIO.Write(value, x, y); }
        }
        public static void WriteLine(string value)
        {
            if (frmIO != null) lock (frmIO) {
                Interactive.Write(value); Interactive.Write("\r\n"); }
        }
        public static int Read()
        {
            if (frmIO != null) lock (frmIO) {
                string input = frmIO.Read(false);
                if (input.Length > 0) return input[0]; }
            return 0;
        }
        public static string ReadLine()
        {
            if (frmIO != null) lock (frmIO) { return frmIO.Read(true); }
            else return "";
        }
    }
}
```

This last class, `Interactive`, actually serve as invoker for asynchronous methods, and it is used in `Main()` at the beginning.
You can skip this whole second section of code if you don't want to see console window when program is run as a windows service.
I have also created an Installer class for this, but it would be just to much code on this page.

EDIT: This `InteractiveForm` is actually a form with designer class, but very simple, consisting only of `Form` and `EditBox` inside filling its area.

Answer (score 0):

Basicallly you need 3 projects in your solution:

1. Application itself
2. WinService for production
3. Console Application for test purposes

So your application must have some kind of `Start()` method with e.g. infinite loop that does all work and maybe `Stop()` method to stop processing.

Winservice project must contain class derived from `ServiceBase`, it'l have `OnStart`method that calls your application's `Start` and `OnStop` that calls application's `Stop` method.

Next, in console application you do pretty much same - calling `Start` method in console's entry point.

So far for debug you run your console app, and for release you publish your winservice project

Winservice class might look like:

**upd**

Winservice codez:

```
public class MyWinService : ServiceBase
{
    IMyApplicationService _myApplicationService;

    //constructor - resolve dependencies here
    public MyWinService()
    {       
        _myApplicationService = new MyApplicationService();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        base.OnStart(args);
        try
        {
            _myApplicationService.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {      
            //log exception          
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        base.OnStop();
        try
        {
            _myApplicationService.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //log exception             
        }
    }
}
```

Application service:

```
public class MyApplicationService : IMyApplicationService
{
    public MyApplicationService()
    {
        //some initializations
    }

    public Start()
    {
        //do work here
    }

    public Stop()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically. i add a class which is derived from servicebase and add those methods ?